# How to combine multiple output in tensorflow to create a metric?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a multi-task neural net which has two outputs, a segmentation "mask" and a classification "label":

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(352, 512, 3), name='image')
outputs = base_model(inputs)

mask = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='mask')(outputs)

label = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(outputs)
label = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='label')(label)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, [mask, label])
```

From this model I obtain one prediction "mask" and one prediction "label". The question is: I want to create a metric such that it only evaluates the dice coefficient of "mask" when the corresponding "label" > 0.5.

I have been searching this for quite a while and from tensorflow official site I can only find how to calculate metrics for each output, but no documentation on how to access all the predictions and combine them.

```
metrics = {'mask': [dice_coef(threshold=0.5)],
        'label': [tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy]}
```

here each metric only accept two arguments (y_true, y_pred).

Update:

I have figured out a work around myself, instead of combining results in the metrics, I added one lambda layer in the network and added one more output

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(352, 512, 3), name='image')
outputs = base_model(inputs)

mask = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='mask')(outputs)

label = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(outputs)
label = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='label')(label)

label_exp = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda label: tf.cast(tf.math.greater(label, 0.5), tf.float32))(label)
label_exp = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([1,1,4])(label_exp)
filtered = tf.keras.layers.Multiply(name='filtered')([mask, label_exp])

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, [mask, filtered, label])
```

And the metrics now is set to be:

```
metrics = {'mask': [dice_coef(threshold=0.5)],
            'filtered': [dice_coef(threshold=0.5)],
            'label': [tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy]}
```

This works but seems like will cost additional memory. Still looking for a neat solution...